# conditionally update values using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, imputation

I'm doing some data manipulation for a survey data and it is killing me... So here is what I encountered. I got two data frames, df1 is the survey data, df2 is the question visiting history of each respondent. 1 = respondent visited the question, 0 = respondent didn't visit the question. What I'm trying to do is to distinguish the NA in the survey data caused by respondent refused to answer vs. NA caused by respondent didn't visit the question. The logic I was hoping to achieve is

```
if df2$var == 0, then df1$var <- "does not apply"
```

The data frames were structured like this:

df1 : survey data

| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a | NA | a |
| 2 | b | NA | b | b |
| 3 | c | c | NA | c |
| 4 | NA | d | NA | d |

df2:  visiting history

| ID | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Since this a large dataset and I have to impute this "does not apply" to all the variables I assume I have to use a loop, but I'm not sure how to write it... What I can think of is just the baseR function like this. Can someone give me a hint on how to write a loop to do this? Many thanks!

```
df1$var1[df2$var1 == 0] <- "Does Not Apply"
df1$var2[df2$var2 == 0] <- "Does Not Apply"
df1$var3[df2$var3 == 0] <- "Does Not Apply"
df1$var4[df2$var4 == 0] <- "Does Not Apply"
```

Comment: Does this provide enough of hint to get you started: `df1[df2[ , 1]==0 , 1] <- "Does not apply"`

Answer (score 0):

A loop shouldn't be necessary if you can match up the chunks of `df1` and `df2` that you wish to directly compare:

```
cols <- c("var1","var2","var3")
df1[cols][df2[cols]==0] <- "Does Not Apply"

##  ID           var1           var2           var3 var4
##1  1              a              a Does Not Apply    a
##2  2              b Does Not Apply              b    b
##3  3              c              c           <NA>    c
##4  4 Does Not Apply              d Does Not Apply    d
```